# Changing a displayed <div> with another <div> when a link was clicked using php

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to ask some help on this thing. I created a site that has a lot of div and what I want is that when a link is clicked only one div will be displayed without reloading the whole page.

Sample code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Div 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Div 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Div 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content1">
    <p>This is content 1</p>
</div>
<div id="content2">
    <p>This is content 2</p>
</div>
<div id="content3">
    <p>This is content 13</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible if I'll just use php? And please help me on how I will do it.

Comment: You need to use something like jquery to do client sided events.

Comment: Why would you want to only use PHP? if there a reason as this is a JavaScript job.

Comment: You need javascript, if you want PHP then use AJAX

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/sXqnD/15/

Comment: I'm not used to javascript as of now @JamieTaylor. That's why I am thinking if there are ways to do it with php.

Comment: As long as you have a good mind for programming, the logic for most of these things is the same, I'd look into jquery.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @JamieTaylor. Your right, I really have to use javascript to do this.

Comment: I already solved this problem of mine! Thanks guys for all of your suggestions. (cheers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQUERY tabs for achieve this one..

Please look at http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Thanks for your answer and this is a good suggestion. But I don't like to use tabs for my current project. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below scripts

```
<a href="" onclick="showdiv('content1'); ">Div 1</a>
   <a href="" onclick="showdiv('content2'); ">Div 2</a>
   <a href="" onclick="showdiv('content3'); ">Div 3</a>


<scripts>
var hidediv = null;
function showdiv(id) {
    if(hidediv)
       hidediv();
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = 'block';
    hidediv = function () { div.style.display = 'none'; };
}
</scripts>
```